# Turning a span into an input box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to turn a certain number of span elements into input boxes, whenever i click the edit button, and back to span when i click another one,but i'm facing some issues:

Here's my fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2D9FW/173/)

And my code:

HTML:

```
<span id="1">hedh</span>
<br />
<span id="2">2222eh3222222</span>
<br />
<span id="3">333333eh33333</span>
<br />
<span id="4">44444eher44444</span>
<br />
<span id="5">555555edgt5555</span>
<br />

<button id="edit_properties">Edit</button>
<button id="unedit_properties">Save</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
  var switchToInput = function(id_value) {
  var $input = $("<input>", {
    val: $(this).text(),
    type: "text"
  });
  $input.attr("ID", id_value);
  $(this).replaceWith($input);
  $input.select();
};
var switchToSpan = function(id_value) {
  var $span = $("<span>", {
    text: $(this).val()
  });
  $span.attr("ID", id_value);
  $(this).replaceWith($span);
  $span.on("click", switchToInput);
}
$("#edit_properties").on("click", function() {

    switchToInput(1);
    switchToInput(2);
    switchToInput(3);
    switchToInput(4);
    switchToInput(5);

});
 $("#unedit_properties").on("click", function() {

    switchToSpan(1);
    switchToSpan(2);
    switchToSpan(3);
    switchToSpan(4);
    switchToSpan(5);

});
```

Comment: What are the issues?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it doens't work. I would say that's the principal one

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan when i click the edit button, all the text remains as text

Comment: Have you at least checked the console for any errors?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it doens't have any syntax errors

Comment: Well, your HTML is invalid as it should be `<br />`, not `</br>`. Also when you click the `edit` button you get this in the console: `jquery-1.9.1.js:5823 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined`. Also numeric `id` attributes cause problems in certain browsers. I would suggest you change them to alpha numeric. The major cause of the error is because the scope of `this` in the function will be the window, not the `span` as you seem to be assuming.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you elaborate an answer ?

Comment: I added one for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues with your code:

- The `</br>` elements should be `<br />`
- Numeric `id` attribute values cause issues in certain browsers. You should change them to alphanumeric.
- When you click the `edit` button you get an error in the console:

  > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined
- The scope of `this` will be the `window` not the `span`

The last point is the major issue with your code.

To fix this you can put a common class on all the `span`/`input` elements, and provide a function to `replaceWith()` that builds the appropriate element to perform the replacement. Try this:

```js
$("#edit_properties").on("click", function() {
  $('.editable-span').replaceWith(function() {
    return $("<input>", {
      val: $(this).text(),
      type: "text",
      id: this.id,
      class: 'editable-input'
    });
  });
});

$("#unedit_properties").on("click", function() {
  $('.editable-input').replaceWith(function() {
    return $("<span>", {
      text: this.value,
      id: this.id,
      class: 'editable-span'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="s1" class="editable-span">hedh</span><br />
<span id="s2" class="editable-span">2222eh3222222</span><br />
<span id="s3" class="editable-span">333333eh33333</span><br />
<span id="s4" class="editable-span">44444eher44444</span><br />
<span id="s5" class="editable-span">555555edgt5555</span><br />

<button id="edit_properties">Edit</button>
<button id="unedit_properties">Save</button>
```

Alternatively you could not bother with the `edit` or `save` buttons at all and just set the `contenteditable="true"` attribute on the `span` elements.

Comment: Just a simple question: if i wanted to make the input boxes the full width and height of the spans, how would i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace $(this) with $('span#'+id_value) in switchtoInput function and it works.

```js
    var switchToInput = function(id_value) {
      var $input = $("<input>", {
        val: $('span#'+id_value).text(),
        type: "text"
      });
      $input.attr("ID", id_value);
      $('span#'+id_value).replaceWith($input);
      $input.select();
    };
    var switchToSpan = function() {
      var $span = $("<span>", {
        text: $(this).val()
      });
      $span.attr("ID", "loadNum");
      $(this).replaceWith($span);
      $span.on("click", switchToInput);
    }
    $("#edit_properties").click(function() {
        switchToInput(1);
        switchToInput(2);
        switchToInput(3);
        switchToInput(4);
        switchToInput(5);
     
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="1">hedh</span>
</br>
<span id="2">2222eh3222222</span>
</br>
<span id="3">333333eh33333</span>
</br>
<span id="4">44444eher44444</span>
</br>
<span id="5">555555edgt5555</span>
</br>

<button id="edit_properties">Edit</button>
<button id="unedit_properties">Save</button>
```